# Install Droidcam pc client for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: droidcam

```
sudo apt-get install droidcam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package droidcam
```

How to install Droidcam client for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

Droidcam isn't available for Ubuntu 16.04 and probably never will be because it hasn't been updated since almost 2 years ago.

Up to Ubuntu 15.04 you could have used [this instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/install-droidcam-wireless-android.html).

Comment: i have tried already its not working for me.

Comment: Of course it isn't, that's exactly what I explained in the very first sentence. Please read carefully and understand that the latest version in the PPA is for 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

Since Droidcam isn't currently available for 16.04 and has a number of unresolved [issues](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/droidcam/issues), [Smartcam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartcam/) is an alternative that you might find useful:
If you must have Droidcam you could consider running 12.04 or 14.04 instead but it seems it's not compatible with the current Android version so I'd give it a pass.

Note that there is a Stack Exchange site designed expressly for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) that you might occasionally find useful.

Comment: smartcam isn't working for me

Comment: That sounds like a new question. Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and then open a new question with sufficient detail for us to respond in an intelligent fashion. "Not working for me" does not provide any clues for us to work with. If that doesn't appeal to you you can also try Software Recommendations link in my answer above. Note that they too have guidelines for questions: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask